# Which folder allows any user to create/edit/delete files?

Tags: windows, file-permissions

Does anyone here know a folder that is not located in `C:\users\*` that let's any user modify/create/delete files independent of their privilege level and user account?

Comment: Short answer: no, not by default in windows vista+, %TEMP% is now in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp

Answer (score 2):

You would need to

1. create a folder, and
2. Change its permissions to give anyone access. This can be done from the properties dialog for the folder.

You don't even need to be an administrator to do (2), but if you want to put it somewhere "central" versus somewhere in your user directory, you'll need admin access for (1).